# What does Spring do if spring.beaninfo.ignore is set to true?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I noticed Spring Boot set `spring.beaninfo.ignore` as true if it's not set. What does Spring do with respect to this property?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/CachedIntrospectionResults.html

Answer (score 1):

**"spring.beaninfo.ignore"**, with a value of "true" means skipping the search for BeanInfo classes (typically for scenarios where no such classes are being defined for beans in the application in the first place).

The default is "false", considering all BeanInfo metadata classes, like for standard Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class) calls.  
Consider switching this flag to "true" if you experience repeated ClassLoader access for non-existing BeanInfo classes, in case such access is expensive on startup or on lazy loading.

Comment: Not sure if it's changed since you posted this, but the default is `true`, not `false`, per Spring's [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.beaninfo.ignore) documentation.